# Django model data not appearing

Tags: html, django, django-models

My model data for my website wont appear on new page when using slug and I am unsure as to why this is happening as I managed to get it to work with the previous page of the website but when I try to call it on my html page nothing will load now and I use the slug in the view to access the page.

Models.py

```
class Parasite(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=100000)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='parasite_images', default='default/default.jpg', blank=True)
        
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Parasite, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def view_parasite(request,parasite_name_slug):
    context_dict = {}
    try:
        parasite = Parasite.objects.get(slug=parasite_name_slug)
        context_dict['parasites'] = parasite
    except Parasite.DoesNotExist:
       context_dict['parasites'] = None
    return render(request, 'parasites_app/viewpara.html', context = context_dict)
```

viewpara.html

```
{% extends 'parasites_app/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content_block %}


{% for p in parasite %}
    <h3>{{p.name}}</h3>
   
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
 urlpatterns = [
           
        
             path('login/', views.user_login, name='login'),
                path('logout/', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
                path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                path('', views.public, name='public'),
                path('public/', views.public, name='public'),
                path('private/', views.logged_in_content, name='private'),
                path('public/<slug:parasite_name_slug>/',views.view_parasite, name='view_parasite'),
                path('<slug:post_name_slug>/', views.show_post, name='show_post'),
               
        
          
           
          
        ]
        
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
        urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1):

First mistake - you are getting one `Parasite` object (cause you use method `get`) and you call it with plural name `'parasites'`:

```
parasite = Parasite.objects.get(slug=parasite_name_slug)
context_dict['parasites'] = parasite
```

Second mistake - when you want to show it in template, you call for single `parasite`, but you decided to name the key `parasites`.

```
{% for p in parasite %}
```

Third mistake - don't use `for` loop for one object, just call it.

Answer:

views.py

```
parasite = Parasite.objects.get(slug=parasite_name_slug)
context_dict['parasite'] = parasite
```

viewpara.html

```
{% block content_block %}

    {{ parasite.name }}

{% endblock %}
```